# Epicene pronoun reference resolution ambiguity

Tags: pronouns, disambiguities

**Context:** I am developing resolution strategies of 2nd-person *you* sequences into 3rd-person epicene (gender-neutral, singular) *they* sequences. These are unique recombinable sequences, not unlike a chatbot. The majority, in this case, have been solvable through simple rule-based string replacement with perplexity scoring for objective (*them*) cases, and a distinct strategy for imperative and prohibitive statements.

**Problem:** I am coming up against a seemingly hard limit, however, for sequences that contain both a reference to a plural *they* and the singular epicene *they*. Tokenization and dependency parsing as so far yield little to start with. SpaCy has been my primary software.

(Note in the examples below that were the pronoun not the epicene use of *they* but gendered, the ambiguity would be solved. This is however not an option.)

**Examples:**

1. "When someone plays games with you, they make the rules." *becomes* "When someone plays games with them, they make the rules."
2. "There are no rules but the ones you make with each other." *becomes* "There are no rules but the ones they make with each other."
3. "Frustration and delays will occur. They will ultimately teach you persistence." *becomes* "Frustration and delays will occur. They will ultimately teach them persistence."

And so on.

**Questions:**

1. Is there anything missing from my understanding of the problem? Am I articulating it adequately?
2. Would coreference modeling be able to sort out the difference between the anaphora?
3. What else should I attempt in order to flag these? I don't need to "resolve" them necessarily.

Comment: Why not replace all 2nd person 'you' references with 1st person 'one' ? It works with all of your examples.

Comment: I can't see how "you" (meaning "one") can be replaced with "they", which in the singular usually replaces "he" or "she". In your sentences it isn't clear who "they" and "them" are, which looks like plural anyway, not singular. The use of "they" comes across as from someone who is miles above and away from mere humans.

Comment: Could you explain why you think such a system is needed?   Users of English are collectively finding their messy way through this awareness of of the grammatical dominance of the masculine.  They dump the sequence of number rule.  Some grammatical sticklers say this is wrong.  But it has come established.  Sticklers have no trouble getting around it, even if at times stiltedly.  The grammatically easy thing would be to drop gender pronouns and use the neutral neuter ‘it’.  The problem is obvious, but it is logical.  We don’t need gendered plural pronouns.  but leave it to natural selection.

Comment: Are you missing "someone" in "When plays games with them"

Comment: @NigelJ That was an earlier solve, but significantly changes the meaning of the sentence, the idea is to remove all reference to 2nd person

Comment: @WeatherVane agreed, but like the 3rd example not all are impersonal "you"

Comment: @Tuffy its automated writing for a product

Comment: @Barmar indeed, edited

Comment: @mbembem I understand that.  But why would you not have it do what the majority do?  Or you could provide rule options, like one for old fashioned traditionalists with absolute gender consistency with masculine the default gender; one for enlightened traditionalists, with ‘he or she’  where gender is not specified; standard, for those that want to follow the majority practice.  You could call this a ‘style guide’, like those that serious newspapers and civil servant departments use.